# Difference between grammar productions and derivations

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars

My understanding is that a production is a 'rule' of a grammar which defines how a symbol sequence can be rewritten into another symbol sequence.

A derivation on the other hand is the process of forming a new symbol sequence by following the rules (productions?) of the grammar.

The Wikipedia-page in my language contradicts me here and my English isn't good enough to understand the english one so I would be very thankful for a correction or better explanation of this matter.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Have you checked the "Talk" page of the Wikipedia article (in your language)? If there is nothing there, you should consider mentioning the mistake (or even correcting it yourself).

Comment: Are you learning the theory of formal-language and formal grammars from a modern textbook or Wikipedia? Popular textbooks are much better than Wikipedia for beginners in general.

Comment: @dkaeae Thanks I corrected/clarified the article. Should I delete this question since there won't be an answer? What is the procedure in this case?

Comment: @Apass.Jack I am studying it in university and tried looking it up since I wasn't sure about it and got even more confused by WIkipedia